# Telit GE910 SSL protocol with Firebase

Tags: ssl, https, arduino, firebase

I'm making a project with Arduino and a Telit GE910 QUAD V3 GPRS  board, I want to datalog in Firebase but I'm having problems, I cannot use external libs to make http requests because I have to follow the GPRS AT commands syntax. Do you think is possible to have a workaround for SSL protocol?
my main problem is that the certificate is too big and this protocol seems too heavy for my ATMEGA328P-MU.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html) to make HTTPS requests directly to the Firebase API.

For example, I can perform a POST request to https://`<instance>`.firebaseio.com/path/to/data.json to write data, and a GET request to the same URL to read it back.

You can try this out from the command line using a demo server:

```
> curl -X PUT -d '{ "first": "Michael", "last": "Wulf" }' https://sample-rest-endpoint.firebaseio-demo.com/users/kato/name.json

> curl https://sample-rest-endpoint.firebaseio-demo.com/users/kato/name.json
```